# HP G61 Notebook: TCP seems to be dead

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, tcp

Can't say I'm much of a Windows expert, but this is somewhat of a weird occurence. I'm in front of a HP G61 Notebook laptop with Win7 that has connectivity problems. I mean that it's connected to the local network, Windows is absolutely convinced it can access the Internet, pinging arbitrary domains and IP addresses works, name resolution works too (and therefore must work UDP), but I can't connect to any website, or open MSN, or stuff like that. Even the Java Updater can't connect.

This is not a router issue, as other computers on the network can access the Internet. We also tried to join another wireless network, and found the same problems. Even with a wired connection, the same things happen.

My guess is that somehow, TCP is dead.

I've tried a bunch of things: restart the network adapter, [reset the TCP/IP stack](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299357), [reset WinSock too](http://bizsupport1.austin.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?objectID=c01881145&lang=en&cc=us&taskId=110&contentType=SupportFAQ&prodSeriesId=3948279&prodTypeId=321957#A1), but nothing works.

Any idea?

Comment: the default gateway setting is correct ?

Comment: @Sathya Yes. It is the automatic gateway address obtained with DHCP. Besides, if it wasn't valid, I wouldn't be able to ping outside the LAN.

Comment: Use IE to do a reset, its in the Tools>Internet Options>Advanced Tab, this resets more than the IE browser.

Comment: @Moab I've already reset TCP/IP and WinSock doing `netsh int ip reset` and `netsh winsock reset`. This is not a computer I own, so I can't just test whatever gets suggested as I need a bit of traveling. :/

Comment: Is TCP really dead?  At the command line, type `telnet www.google.com 80` <Enter> `GET / HTTP/1.0` <Enter> <Enter>.  If you get some HTTP+HTML spew, then I would suspect your system's proxy configuration.  If you don't, then I would suspect a firewall somewhere.

Comment: @ephemient The laptop doesn't have `telnet`. Trying it was my first reflex.

Comment: You can add `telnet` by opening Control Panel, finding Programs, then Windows Features, selecting Telnet Client, and finishing the wizard.

Comment: @zneak, it does not fix tcpip, it does however fix your proxy and firewall settings among other things. You know, the little stuff we never think of when trying to fix internet connectivity issues. No guarantee it will sove your issue.

Comment: @Moab We checked that there is no proxy, and we disabled the firewall for a test run. These two aren't the issues.

Comment: @ephemient I'll tell them to try that.